# Get data from another model

Tags: laravel

```
$objects = Objects::where("id_host", $hostId)
    ->orderBy("id", "desc")
    ->get();
```

In the collection , each object has a type_id field . How can I use this field to get a record in another model and mix them into this object in the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is first, in order to show the relationship between the records, you'll need to set up a [One-to-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)/[Many-to-One](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) relationship. This allows you to readily call those relationships from within Laravel and to load them together.

Without being able to see your `Type` and `Object` classes, I really can't give specific advice on this, but it should look something like this:

**Objects**

```
public function type(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Type::class);
}
```

**Type**

```
public function objects(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Objects::class);
}
```

Once you've done that, you can add a [`with(...)`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) call to your Eloquent query to eager load the relationship.

```
$objects = Objects::where("id_host", $hostId)
    ->orderBy("id", "desc")
    ->with('type')
    ->get();
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to eager load it for some reason, you can call `$object->type` to get the Type object.